# Observable<unknown> is not assignable to Observable<{}>.It is missing the following properties like name,email,isAdmin

Tags: javascript, angular, observable

I am returning observable with generic object and if user exists returning user object otherwise returning null. But in this process I am getting an error like:

> observable<-unknown-> is not assign to observable<{}>.``` And it is missing the following properties.

auth.service.ts

```js
import { AppUser } from './models/app-users';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

export class AuthService {

constructor(private userObj:UserService) 

 get appUser$(): Observable<AppUser | null> {
    return this.user$.pipe(
      switchMap(user => user
        ? this.userObj.get<AppUser>(user.uid).valueChanges()
        : of(null)
      )
    );
  }
```

user.service.ts:

```js
 get(uid:string):AngularFireObject<AppUser>{
    return this.db.object('/users/' + uid);
  }
```

*app-users.ts*:

```js
export interface AppUser {
    name: string;
    email: string;
    isAdmin: boolean;
}
```

How to return null if user doesn't exists?

Comment: Try parametrizing `of`:  `Observable.of<AppUser>(null)`

Comment: @VladVidac : When i am trying to return the this statement. It is showing the same error.

Answer (score 5):

You should do it like this, by changing the return type. I guess you are using the `strict: true` option in your tsconfig.json :

```
get appUser$(): Observable<AppUser | null> {
  return this.user$.pipe(
    switchMap(user => user
      ? this.userObj.get(user.uid).valueChanges()
      : of(null)
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: @SrinivasNeelamraju I've updated my answer. Perhaps the issue is that the `this.userObj.get`, is a generic function that needs a type. Can you show me type of `this.userObj` if that doesn't work? Also, how are you importing the `of` operator

Comment: @SrinivasNeelamraju you should use `of` like in my answer, instead of `Observable.of`